# Groovy - How to compare the string?

Tags: groovy

how to compare the string which is passed as a parameter

the following method is not working.

```
 String str = "saveMe"

 compareString(str)

 def compareString(String str){
    def str2 = "saveMe"
    if(str2==${str}){
      println "same"
    }else{
      println "not same"
    }
 }
```

also tried

```
 String str = "India"

 compareString(str)

 def compareString(String str){
   def str2 = "india"
   if( str2 == str ) {
     println "same"
   }else{
     println "not same"
   }
 }
```

Comment: `India` is not the same as `india`.  The first character is different

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This line:

```
if(str2==${str}){
```

Should be:

```
if( str2 == str ) {
```

The `${` and `}` will give you a parse error, as they should only be used inside Groovy Strings for templating

Comment: @user1602802 It does in the groovy console.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: @user1602802 Are you comparing `India` with a capital `I` and `india` with a lower-case `i` like in the edit to your question?  `India != india`. They are different.

Comment: Coming from Java this might seem wrong but `==` operator does string comparison like `equals` in Groovy.

Answer (score 154):

This should be an answer:

```
str2.equals( str )
```

If you want to ignore case:

```
str2.equalsIgnoreCase( str )
```

Comment: Downvoting because the original question did not specify that it should ignore care. Also, groovy supports the `==` operator for string comparison (in contrast with Java, where `==` does identity comparison, not string comparison).

Comment: I adjusted the answer to be case sensitive

Comment: Is there a short alias for equalsIgnoreCase in Groovy?

Comment: I think you could create a wrapper function called eIC or something similar.  Depends on how much it actually bugs you.

Comment: Warning. `.equals()` does *not* behave the same in Groovy as it does in Java.  Example [here](http://grails.asia/groovy-compare-string) -- scroll down to 'GString and String'. Basically both items have to be of the same type of String class. Since the String class is implicit in the assignment -- GString is a Groovy language construct and String is an inline definition, something like `def foo = "foo"` ... `"${foo}".equals("foo")` will return `false`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to check on upper or lowercases you can use the following method.

```
String str = "India" 
compareString(str) 

def compareString(String str){ 
  def str2 = "india" 
  if( str2.toUpperCase() == str.toUpperCase() ) { 
    println "same" 
  }else{ 
    println "not same" 
  } 
}
```

So now if you change str to "iNdIa" it'll still work, so you lower the chance that you make a typo.

Comment: `str2.equalsIgnoreCase( str )` is probably easier to read :-)

Comment: @tim_yates not only is it easier to read, it is also more correct. Case conversions such as these are prone to locale errors (Turkish I etc).

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way (will print "not same" because String comparison is case sensitive):

```
def compareString = {
   it == "india" ? "same" : "not same"
}    

compareString("India")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "saveMe"
compareString(str)

def compareString(String str){
  def str2 = "saveMe"

  // using single quotes
  println 'single quote string class' + 'String.class'.class
  println str + ' == ' + str2 + " ? " + (str == str2)
  println ' str = ' +  '$str' //  interpolation not supported

  // using double quotes, Interpolation supported
  println "double quoted string with interpolation " + "GString.class $str".class
  println "double quoted string without interpolation " + "String.class".class
  println "$str equals $str2 ? " + str.equals(str2) 
  println '$str == $str2 ? ' + "$str==$str2"
  println '${str == str2} ? ' + "${str==str2} ? "

  println '$str equalsIgnoreCase $str2 ? ' + str.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)   

  println '''
  triple single quoted Multi-line string, Interpolation not supported $str ${str2}
  Groovy has also an operator === that can be used for objects equality
  === is equivalent to o1.is(o2)
  '''
  println '''
  triple quoted string 
  '''
  println 'triple single quoted string ' + '''' string '''.class

  println """ 
  triple double quoted Multi-line string, Interpolation is supported $str == ${str2}
  just like double quoted strings with the addition that they are multiline
  '\${str == str2} ? ' ${str == str2} 
  """
  println 'triple double quoted string ' + """ string """.class
}
```

output:

```
single quote string classclass java.lang.String
saveMe == saveMe ? true
str = $str
double quoted string with interpolation class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
double quoted string without interpolation class java.lang.String
saveMe equals saveMe ? true
$str == $str2 ? saveMe==saveMe
${str == str2} ? true ? 
$str equalsIgnoreCase $str2 ? true 

triple single quoted Multi-line string, Interpolation not supported $str ${str2}
Groovy has also an operator === that can be used for objects equality
=== is equivalent to o1.is(o2)


triple quoted string 

triple single quoted string class java.lang.String

triple double quoted Multi-line string, Interpolation is supported saveMe == saveMe
just like double quoted strings with the addition that they are multiline
'${str == str2} ? ' true 

triple double quoted string class java.lang.String
```

Answer (score -3):

In Groovy, `null == null` gets a `true`. At runtime, you won't know what happened.
In Java, `==` is comparing two references.

This is a cause of big confusion in basic programming, Whether it is safe to use equals. At runtime, a null.equals will give an exception. You've got a chance to know what went wrong.

Especially, you get two values from keys not exist in map(s), `==` makes them equal.

Answer (score -7):

use def variable, when you want to compare any String. Use below code for that type of comparison.

def variable name = null

SQL query give you some return. Use function with return type def.

def functionname(def variablename){

return variable name

}

if ("$variable name" == "true"){

}