# Why isn't the subreport displayed when I change the language property from groovy to java

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I have a report with a subreport inside.

This subreport have property "Print when expresion" activated (a simple expression `$field == string`). It works fine, but if i change the "language" property in main report from "groovy" to "java", the subreport never appears

(I'm using IReports 5.6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) you will compare two String's using `==`

see [Groovy - How to compare the string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984350/groovy-how-to-compare-the-string)

Instead in [java](/questions/tagged/java) you need to use `.equals()`, `$field.equals(string)`

see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I changed my code (.equals()) and it works OK. Thank you Peter